# Stupidly moved a .pdf file to /dev/sda1 and Ubuntu crashed

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

Story short, I was trying to mount my USB and ended up moving a .pdf file to `/dev/sda1`. The system crashed and when booting, it takes me to the GRUB recovery. Now I entered the system with a Ubuntu Live USB and when running the command `file -s /dev/sda1`, I get `dev/sda1: PDF document, version 1.5`
Anybody knows how to solve this?

Comment: Get a copy of `testdisk` it recovered my data for me. It might work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

You have essentially destroyed whatever file system was on /dev/sda1. What was it? Ext? Btrfs? Was it root or boot partition? May be you could try to boot from USB stick to fix the filesystem with `fsck`. Anyway, we need info about partition to provide you with exact commands.
EDIT: After a bit of thinking: even if you would repair the file system, you will still be missing some crucial system files most likely. In short, you should better reinstall Ubuntu. It will take less time than finding out what is missing and where to get it.